# Do transits count as days towards an overstay in South Africa?

Tags: south-africa

My daughter flew into South Africa (SA) and then straight out to volunteer in Namibia. She then returned to SA for a volunteering stint in Cape Town.

On leaving, she was challenged that she had overstayed her stay by 2 days. They were counting from the 'in transit' stop over. She was eventually allowed to continue. She is due to go back soon but is worried she is flagged as undesirable? We have tried everything to find out if she has been but got no where. Any advice? Would she have been given a document if she was flagged?

Comment: if she has overstayed, British travel advice states "If you overstay, you are likely to be declared undesirable and denied entry into South Africa in future. The enforcement of these penalties is strict, and appeals can take many months to process." https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/south-africa/entry-requirements

Comment: Worth noting that for 90 days to be reset the visitor has to return to their country of residence before returning to SA, so the trip to Namibia, then coming back, wont have reset her 90 days.

Comment: Yes, I believe @BritishSam comment is correct. Upon entry, with neighboring visas, a multiple enter visa is issued where the whole 90 days count from the first entry to the last exit. Could not find a official source making that statement however.

Comment: When she "transited", did she enter South Africa, i.e. go through passport control/immigration in and out? Does she have South Africa entry/exit stamps in her passport?

Comment: @jcaron, she has passport entry stamp and passport departure stamp for the transit day.(21stApril) then passport control entry back on 18th May and subsequent departure 28th July.